# UIWebView - Pulling the web view down and then converting it to an image makes a blank band appear at the top and missing info at the bottom?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uigraphicscontext

UIWebView - Pulling the web view down and then converting it to an image makes a blank band appear at the top and missing info at the bottom?

Using this code to take an image screenshot of a long and slim web view. It work fine, but if I *force pull it down* and then take the screenshot, **depending on the background color I have set I get a blank band at the top and the same size missing at the bottom.**

I don't get it? How is this supposed to work?

```
- (UIImage *)convertToImage
{

    // tempframe to reset view size after image was created
    CGRect originalFrame         = self.frame;

    // set new Frame
    CGRect frameForEntirePage = self.frame;
    frameForEntirePage.size.height  = [self sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
    self.frame = frameForEntirePage;

    // do image magic
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]);

    CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // reset Frame of view to origin
    self.frame = originalFrame;

    return image;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Apple decided that UIWebView should adjust the scrollview it contains to an inset, this is so since iOS 7 came out.

To disable this and the resulting headache I had to use:

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO];
```

Or you can select the View Controller in the Storyboard where the Web View resides and uncheck this:

[image: Adjust Scroll View Insets]